# FullCalendar select rectangle instead of full day

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar and allowing the user to make selections to create off-times. Is it possible to allow selecting multiple days, but instead of the **standard behavior:**

[image: FullCalendar selection default behavior]

select only the rectangle between the start and end time.

**Desired behavior:**

[image: FullCalendar desired behavior]

I'm OK with still having one Start date/time and one End date/time. I don't need an array of selections (one per each day selected) as I'm handling that fine in the backend already.

Using FullCalendar v3.9.0.

Comment: you can't do that because it's not a single continuous period of time, and therefore can't be represented by a single event. Therefore you can select it as a single period of time. If you'd like to change that, I would suggest submitting a feature request to the maintainers (see https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features)

Comment: Sorry typo above, I meant you _can't_ select it as a single period of time

Comment: @ADyson isn't it possible to override the render of the selection? It would be still a single period of time but instead of painting between `start` and `end`, it would paint between the dates and between the times of the start and end periods.

Comment: If you're prepared to edit the fullCalendar source code, you can do whatever you like. There's no existing feature to do it. But you're incorrect, it's not a single period of time. It's two separate periods of time, which will need to be represented by two separate event objects, so you'd have to have a totally different signature for the `select` callback as well to return an array of selections.

Comment: @ADyson what I'm saying is, it can be represented as a single start and end. Because I only need to change how the selection works (not the events), if there's a render function that gets called for each time slot, it would be enough to decide whether to paint it or not.

Comment: " it can be represented as a single start and end"...no it can't. Consider your example: With a single start and end, how do I know if you mean the whole time from 21/03 02:00 to 22/03 03:30, or you actually mean 21/03 02:00-03:30 and 22/03 02:00-03:30? There's no way, with a single start and end, to make that distinction. But really, it's clear - it means the first one, because you're describing a single continuous period of time. There's no data in there to describe a break in that block of time.

Comment: The way you're asking the system to be, that would end up being ambiguous. Also, how would you know whether user _wanted_ to select the whole time period, or just the parts you've highlighted, from the mouse drag? It's not possible to know the user's real intent if you implement your suggestion. I think that's a good reason why this feature does not exist. Perhaps you'd have to have a flag the user can set which determines the selection "mode" or something, and which controls how the mouse drag is interpreted.

Comment: @ADyson I had this working on another calendar for 10yrs. I'm moving to FullCalendar now, so yes, it's possible. Stop insisting if you don't know how to do it in FC. Of course there's no way to know the 'intent' of the user, I would just change the behavior for everyone. If the user selected `21/03 02:00` to `22/03 03:30`, you would just ***paint*** the slots `21/03 02:00-03:30` and `22/03 02:00-03:30`.

Comment: So then you're removing functionality whereby the user can select the whole time period. Whereas right now nothing stops them from doing what you're describing, albeit via two selections, _or_ selecting the entire period. I think that's anti-user personally, because it reduces functionality. Unless you foresee in your crystal ball that the users will never want to do anything other than select time in this exact way? And no, I don't know the details of the technical solution - like I said, you'd have to edit the source code. But we're discussing the requirement/feature, not the code.

Comment: Are you really trying to make a shortcut to implement recurring events? It might be more flexible to have a form instead where the user can specify the recurrence. What if the event should recur more days than are shown on the calendar (e.g. repeat for 6 months or something)? By dragging, there's no way to specify that. Whether you had this kind of thing working before in another package or not is not my point - I'm trying to get you to justify why it's a good idea at all. My opinion is that it's not, that's all. I don't think it's user-friendly. If you disagree, go ahead and try to do it

Comment: What you're saying is wrong because of the way the system works. Those are off-times and never go beyond one day, but people might want to mark an off-time for M-F 12pm to 1pm. No need to discuss the use cases really. Question is: **is there any way to overwrite the paint for selections?**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167183/discussion-between-diego-jancic-and-adyson).

Comment: Answer is (as mentioned in a very early comment): probably, but there's no existing feature for it, you'll have to study and modify the source code yourself. At least now you explained a bit of the context. I only argued because sometimes on this site people ask for X when really they want Y, because they're trying to work round a mistake or misunderstanding, or just don't consider all the consequences of doing X. Just wanted to check you weren't storing up problems for yourself, but it seems like you are clear enough about what it entails, so good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with FullCalendar as-is. I've changed the code to support such option.

Please refer to the following issue, in the initial message a Patch is attached for v3.9.0 of the calendar:

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4119